# Composite functions and fixed point free property

Tags: functions, inverse-function, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points, fixed-point-arithmetics

Given 2 functions: $f: X \to X$ and $g: X \to X$,

1. $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one
2. $f$ and $g$ are fixed point free
3. composite functions $f \circ g$, $\; g \circ f$,
   $\; f^2 \equiv f \circ f\;$ and $\;g^2 \equiv g \circ g$
   are fixed point free

Is it true that, any composite functions constructed from $f$ and $g$, namely,

$ T \equiv f^{m_k} \circ g^{n_k} \circ f^{m_{k-1}} \circ g^{n_{k-1}}
\dots f^{m_1} \circ g^{n_1} \circ g$

($m_i, n_i \in \mathbb{N}_0 \equiv \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$,
$\; i, k \in \mathbb{N} \equiv \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$)

are also fixed point free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and let $g(x) = f(x) = x + 1 \mod 3$

Comment: Oh I see. How silly I am. Thanks!

Comment: What about if I add one more condition? "There is a partition of $X$ into two subsets, and $f$ and $g$ map each of the two subsets into the other one."

Comment: @Phil So maybe write $X =\{x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ and let $f(x_i) = y_{i+1 \mod 3}$ and $f(y_i) = x_{i-1 \mod 3}$, and $g=f$.